# How can I get communication with my Arduino Uno over the serial port to work?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I just got an Arduino starter kit and want to start learning more about working with electronics.

But I have a problem, the *Arduino Tools* → *Serial Port* menu item is greyed out and I do not know how to get it to work.

It may be important to note that the *L* on the board is blinking as though I uploaded the example blink script (blinking corresponds to *Communicating With The Arduino -- Setting Up* in the project book). However, I did not upload the script…

Comment: @Alvar Communication between **Ubuntu** and the Arduino...

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved, Once I ran the program as root I was able to get it to work. In Terminal `sudo arduino`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps to avoid running Arduino IDE as root: http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/All#Permission